# What are the types of elements found in a vector space other than n-tuples?

Tags: linear-algebra

So basically when we talk about vector space, we consider a set of arbitrary elements and some operations in it which constitute it. Most common type of element known is that of n-tuples of say reals. What other varieties of elements exist in a vector space? Can a  set of matrix be considered for constituting a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer only:

A *vector space* is a set in which you can add two of its elements, and multiply any element by a “scalar”, subject to certain rules that I won’t mention here. Any of one those elements may be called a vector, if you like.

Standard example: the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers, where you add them coordinatewise, and multiply by a real scalar $\lambda$ by multiplying each coordinate by that $\lambda$.

Other examples:
$\quad$1. the vector space is the set of all polynomial expressions in a single variable (say $x$), with real coefficients. If you want to call $1-3x+x^2$ a vector, you may, as long as you’ve made it clear that your vector space is some specified set of polynomials (maybe all), satisfying the rules.
$\quad$2. The vector space is $\Bbb R$, the set of real numbers, but the allowed scalars are just the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$. This is an example of an infinite-dimensional vector space *over the rationals*.
$\quad$3. You may want to talk about the totality of all two-by-two matrices with real entries. This is a vector space over the real field $\Bbb R$, of dimension four. A single matrix will be a vector in this space.
$\quad$4. The set of all possible sequences of real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots\,$. You may think of these as inf-tuples of reals, and any one of them would be a vector in this vector space.
$\quad$5. The set of all real sequences as above, but subject to the condition that $\lim_{i\to\infty}a_i$ exists as a real number. You can add any two of these to get another, as you know, and if you take a convergent sequence $\{a_i\}$ you can multiply every term by a given $\lambda$ to get another convergent sequence, as you also know. So that’s a good vector space, too.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will it be correct to say that euclidean space (which contains set of all n-tuples of real numbers) is subset of a vector space then?

Comment: Yes, indeed Euclidean space can be thought of as being a vector space in itself, but… A vector space has a distinguished element (or point), namely the origin. Strictly speaking, Euclidean space has no special points. But once you choose a point to be your origin, *then* Euclidean space becomes a vector space.

Comment: Let's say in an example of n-tuples of reals, we perceive an ordered pair or tuple (which ofcourse is a vector) as point or vector (just element) or a directed line segment (vector passing from origin to the mentioned point). Then how is this concept of origin absent in euclidean space? It seems more like if it's not mentioned in the context of a vector space then there's no problem at all? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Well, it’s delicate point, but on the Euclidean plane, there is no special point. If you’ve *defined* a space to be $\Bbb R^2$, you have actually not defined Euclidean space. Think of your high-school geometry — you don’t start with a point that’s fixed, you talk about points and lines and the relations among them.

Comment: Well I get that but here when we define a space to be $\Bbb R^2$ isn't it supposed to be Euclidean since it satisfies both properties of a vector space (addition, scalar multiplication) as well as metric space (inner dot products, norm and distance) as well?

Comment: It’s a *coordinatized* Euclidean space. What we’re dancing around here is the distinction between affine space and its associated vector space. But I don’t want to get into that in this forum.

Comment: So $\Bbb R^2$ is just a vector space (actually a Cartesian plane). Then how to characterise it as an Euclidean space?

Comment: You just put the standard distance function on it. If you want to discuss this further, you may e-mail me.

Comment: Yeah, that's just it. Thanks for your help